# how to fetch instance from route53 :aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am new to aws cli.

I am trying to fetch associated instances from and Elastic load balancers (which is associated with a Route 53 via alias target). I know my hosted zone id and I use weighted routes behind Route53 (1 for the active).

I was trying to fire following command (but till now only able to fetch resource name or which one is active from weight):

`aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --output text --hosted-zone-id  <myId> --query "ResourceRecordSets[?Name == '<Name>'].[SetIdentifier,Weight]" --output text | awk '$2 == 0 {print $1}'`

How to do this. Please help.

(In short, R53-> 2 ELBs-> EC2s)

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are actually trying to do? What do you mean by "fetch associated instances"? Can you see the information in the Route 53 management console, and you are trying to convert that to a CLI command? Feel free to Edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: I am trying to find all EC2s associated with and ELB. But ELB is ot directly exposed but sitting behind R53.

Answer (score 0):

While the user connects via Route 53 -> ELB -> EC2, the logical links are different within AWS.

First, there is the relationship between an ELB and EC2.

If you are using a Classic Load Balancer, then the instances are registered against the ELB.

If you are using an Application Load Balancer, then the instances are registered to a Target Group, and the ELB uses the Target group.

The Load Balancer has a DNS name that can be associated with a Route 53 Alias or CNAME record.

Therefore, if you are starting with the domain name, you'd need to follow these steps:

- Find the **Route 53** entry associated with the domain name
- Retrieve the Alias or CNAME (depending upon how it is configured) that points to the ELB
- Retrieve information about the **ELB**
- Retrieve information about **Target Groups** associated with the ELB
- Retrieve information about the **EC2 instances** in the Target Group

I would recommend **tracing the relationships in the Management Console**, then trying to formulate an [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command for each relationship. You'd need to script it up to pass parameters between commands, or write it in a programming language using the AWS SDK instead of the CLI.

Comment: Yes correct that is what I am trying to do. But need to figure out how to do the same. So far I was able to get EC2s from ELB only.